# kubectl logs -f missing log lines

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am doing some experiments, as we are obviously losing log lines currently in our Kubernetes setup.

Now as a test, I built a small python script that outputs 500000 log lines one after the other.

When recording this with `kubectl logs -f podname >log.txt` it looks like some lines are missing.
Actually as I am on a quite slow VPN connection here, could it be that these messages are just dropped somehow because of my network speed?

Comment: slow connection speed could be an issue. you could try running your python container on a local minikube instance and see whether lines will get dropped too when connection speed is not an issue or not

Comment: the logs are usually written to file on the node the container is running on to /var/log/containers/<container>. You could check the logs there. You should probably also use a proper logging solution. fluent-bit for examples scapes those log files for you.

Comment: consider using `fluent-bit` as also suggested in the above comment. the overhead of collecting/managing/intigrity/forwarding will be the task of the fluentd/fluent-bit.